# Why am I able to access child methods in the parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a problem with the understanding of inheritance in Java: I am able to access overwritten methods of the child class when I cast it back to the parent class.

As an Example there are given the two following classes:

**The parent one:**

```
public class Parent {
    public void whatAreYou() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}
```

**And a child class:**

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void whatAreYou() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }

    public void onlyChildrenCanDoThis() {
        //...
    }

}
```

**When I now do the following:**

```
        Child c = new Child();
        Parent p = c;
        p.whatAreYou();
```

**I get this output:**

```
child
```

This is very strange for my understanding of inheritance in Java. I would expect to get a `parent` output, because I narrowed the child class to the parent class, and with that I should just have access to variables and methods of the parent class.

This is working with `p.onlyChildrenCanDoThis()`, as I cannot access it, because it is not implemented in the parent class...

...but with overwritten methods Java is not behaving that way! **Why is that?**

Comment: Short answer: Non-static methods are dispatched at runtime. You couldn't make any use of method overrides otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you have done

> child c = new child();

You created Object of Child class and assigned its reference to c.

> parent p = c;

Here you have copied reference of child object to p. Remember the object is still Child's object not parents's object.

> p.whatAreYou();

Here you have called whatAreYou method. you are calling this using reference variable p which is pointing to object of child. hence child's method will be called. 
[image]

Another Interpretation

[image]

Comment: But with you explanation I should still be able to call `p.onlyChildrenCanDoThis()` because `p` is just a reference to `c` ...

Comment: No, you can't, as p is reference variable of Parent which doesn't contains onlyChildrenCanDoThis, so p doens't even know about this method. So it can't store address of this method and hence can't actually call it. It'll throw compile time error

Comment: I have added one more explanation. see to that

Answer (score 3):

What you are dealing with here is [**polymorphism**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). `c` is instantiated as `new child()`, and that is why you get `child` as an output. The fact that `p` is of type `parent` doesn't change that fact, it still points to the instance of `child`.

Answer (score 1):

The output is as it is because of the line `parent p = c;`

Imagine this:

```
class Car {
    public void whatAreYou() {
        System.out.println("Car");
    }
}

class Cadillac extends Car {
    public void whatAreYou() {
        System.out.println("Caddillac");
    }
}
```

If you now say

```
Cadillac coolCar = new Cadillac();
Car testCar = coolCar;
testCar.whatAreYou();
```

It becomes pretty obvious that the output is, "Cadillac", no? This is how you can look at inheritence:

Cadillac objects are allways Cars. Car objects *can be* Cadillacs

Since I explicitly set the Cadillac reference `coolCar` to point to an object of a Cadillac, and the Car reference `testCar`to point to the same object, we get the output "Cadillac"

To make it even more obvious, you could even say

```
Car coolCar = new Cadillac();
Car testCar = coolCar;
testCar.whatAreYou();
```

Comment: Instead of `Car.whatAreYou();` did you mean `testCar.whatAreYou();`?

Comment: I would _not_ call it "obvious" as of course the `Car` is "still" a `Cadillac`, but the `Car` object could not use any of The `Cadillac` variables and methods. Or for my example: With your explanation the parent should still be able to call `p.onlyChildrenCanDoThis()` because (as you say it) "`p` is still a `child`"...

Comment: @Robert Which methods you have access to is defined through what type the reference is, in my case `testCar` is defined as a `Car`. If the actual object is of a subclass, and that subclass overrides any of the methods, you access those instead, but you can't access other methods not defined in the Class your reference is type of (again in this case `Car`)